# Cannot simulate event in Unit Test using Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular15

A filter value field is initially '' and after press keyup event the filter value will be updated with the current filter component value. I coded the next unit text but I can't get the updated value and just get the initially value instead:

```
describe('Component', () => {
    let component: Component1;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component1>;
    let mockDialog: MatDialog;
    let mockDataService: Service1;
    let mockToastr: ToastrService;
    let mockPaginator: MatPaginator;
    let mockSort: MatSort;
    let mockFilterElement: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component1],
            imports: [MatPaginatorModule],
            providers: [
                { provide: MatDialog, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialog', ['open']) },
                { provide: Service1, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Service1', ['fetchData', 'update', 'getAll']) },
                { provide: ToastrService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']) },
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component1);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        mockDialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
        mockDataService = TestBed.inject(Service1);
        mockToastr = TestBed.inject(ToastrService);

        mockPaginator = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatPaginator', ['previousPage', 'nextPage']);
        mockSort = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatSort', ['sort']);

        mockFilterElement = new ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>(document.createElement('input'));

        component.dialog = mockDialog;
        component.dataService = mockDataService;
        component.paginator = mockPaginator;
        component.sort = mockSort;
        component.filter = mockFilterElement;

        component.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(null, mockPaginator, mockSort);

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should handle filter changes', async () => {
        const filterValue = 'test';
        mockFilterElement.nativeElement.value = filterValue;

        await component.ngOnInit();
                
        const event = new Event('keyup');
        mockFilterElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);

        expect(component.dataSource.filter).toBe(filterValue);
    });
  // More Tests...
});
```

COMPONENT

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
    @ViewChild('filter', { static: true }) filter: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(): void {

        Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
            debounceTime(150),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(() => {
            if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
            this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value
        });
    }
```

Comment: maybe try using `fixture.detectChanges()` after you dispatch the event.

Comment: @JakeSmith. Hi, many thanks for your response. No, I tried before and the result is the same. I just past the relevant code of my component hoping it helps. Could be I am using Viewchild?

Comment: @JakeSmith. But you give me the hint. I need to add a await fixture.whenStable(); after your fixture.detectChanges(); Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I need to wait until event keyup is completed. For that I changed my code like this:

```
it('should handle filter changes', async () => {
        const filterValue = 'test';
        mockFilterElement.nativeElement.value = filterValue;

        await component.ngOnInit();
            
    const event = new Event('keyup');
    mockFilterElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    fixture.detechChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    expect(component.dataSource.filter).toBe(filterValue);
});
```

Many thanks @JakeSmith for the hint.